# Return multiple fields for use in a dropdown

Tags: meteor

I have this helper in meteor

```
terms:function(){
    return Terms.find().fetch().map(function(it){ return it.termnames; });
  }
```

which only returns the `termname` but i am also interested in the `_id`.

This is my current html

```
<select name="dd">
{{#each terms}}
<option value="">{{this}}</option>
{{/each}}
</select>
```

How can i return the `termnames` and the `_id` and display them in my view?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a cursor instead of an array, including only the `termnames` key. The `_id` key will automatically be included:

```
terms:function(){
  return Terms.find({},{fields: {termnames: 1});
}

<select name="dd">
  {{#each terms}}
    <option id={{_id}} value="">{{termnames}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

Comment: I cant understand this `{termnames: 1}`.How will i write the other fields,for instance the third field say, `termopeningdate`?.

Comment: `{fields: {termnames: 1, termopeningdate: 1}}`